# How to cancel Ongoing Notification when app is killing in Android Oreo 8.0?

Tags: android

Before Android Oreo 8.0, I use a background service and it's callback onTaskRemoved will be called when app is killing. I used this to cancel Ongoing Notification which will appear when app is running but in the background.

However, Android Oreo totally disables the background service, and the alternative - JobService can't keep alive when app is killed. Yes, startForegroundService is a choice and I tried and it works, however, the Notification will stay when the app is launching, no matter in the foreground or background, which is scary to our users.

I would like to ask whom read this and to see any solution I can refer and try? My goal is very simple - when app is killed due to any reason - crash or be swiped off from recent app - the Ongoing Notification will be canceled immediately.

Thanks.